Parabola as a limit of sequence of function $f(x)=\sum_{k=-n}^{n} |x+k|$
I was fooling around with the following expression:
$|x-3|+|x-2|+|x-1|+|x|+|x+1|+|x+2|+|x+3|$
the graph looks something like this:

similarly for y=$\sum_{i=-5}^{5} |x-i|$

Now if we increment by only 0.01(ie. $y= \sum_{i=-10}^{10} |x-0.01i|$ but vary i from  -10 to 10 we get:

Now my question is , do these graphs $ approximately$ represent parabolas as the value of i gets larger and the increment (call it h) gets smaller? I think of something to do with reimann sums but my efforts till now have proved to be futile. Because this sequence of functions looks like parabolas to me. Or are they completely different like $cosh(x)$?Or maybe thereis no pattern at all and this is just a coincidence?

@ tensorman666 I made an addition to the post (misprint is fixed). It's surprising that the answer is parabola for some $x$ and linear function for other $x$.

@Sergei-Nikolaev thank you for your detailed analysis xD

@ tensorman666 You are welcome!

Update (As @DarkMalthorp wrote, there was a mispint)
$f(x) = \sum_{k=-n}^n |x-k|$. If we see graph of $f(x)$, then $f(0) \to \infty$. So we will use scale transform. Consider
$g_n(x) =\frac{1}{n^2}{f(nx)}.$
Claim. $$g_n(x) \to g(x) =\begin{cases}
2 | x |, \ if \ |x| > 1\\
x^2 + 1, \ if \ |x| \le 1
\end{cases}, \quad n \to \infty.$$
Proof.
$$ g_n(x) = \frac{1}n \sum_{k=-n}^n |x - \frac{k}n| \to \int_{-1}^1 |x - t| dt = g(x) =\begin{cases}
2 | x |, \ if \ |x| > 1\\
x^2 + 1, \ if \ |x| \le 1
\end{cases}$$
So $\frac{1}{n^2}{f(nx)} = g_n(x) \approx g(x)$ and $f(y) \approx n^2 g\big( \frac{y}n \big) $.
Addition: The idea of solution is the next one: we must choose a scaling transformation of both coordinate axes such that after it we get a function that has a finite limit
Addition2: as @Ethan Bolker mentioned, after the rescaling the finite sum is a trapezoidal approximation to the integral

Thank you very much! This was exactly what I was looking for!

@tensorman666 You are welcome!

Nice idea the scaling by $n^2$.

@user Thank you!

Shouldn't the integral be $\int_{-1}^1 |x-t| , dt$ not $\int_{-1}^1 |x-t|^2,dt$?

Clearly $f_n(0) = n(n+1)$ which is not asymptotically $\frac23 n^2$

@DarkMalthorp Yes, my misprint!

@DarkMalthorp The idea is essentially the same: we must choose a scaling transformation of both coordinate axes such that after it we get a function that has a finite limit

https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=integral+from+-1+to+1+of+%7Cx-t%7C+dt

+1 I think it worth noting explicitly that after the rescaling the finite sum is a trapezoidal approximation to the integral.

@EthanBolker I made an addition

The answer is still incorrect. It's $2|x|$ for $|x|>1$ and $x^2+1$ for $|x|\le 1$.

@DarkMalthorp Hope it's true now:) Thank you!

We have that for $a\ge0$
$$f_a(x)=|x-a|+|x+a|=\begin{cases}-2x,\;x\le -a\\2a,\;-a\le x\le a\\2x,\;x\ge a\end{cases}$$
is a even piecewise linear function.
Therefore any function defined by a sum like this
$$f(x)=\sum_{k=-n}^{n} |x+k|$$
is also an even piecewise linear function with constant slope for $|x|\ge n$ while for $k\le x \le k+1$ with $x\ge 0$ we have
$$f(x)=2kx+n(n+1)-k(k+1)$$
and at the points $x=k$
$$f(k)=k^2-k+n(n+1)$$
which is indeed, at these points, a parabola.

In the limit, as $n\to \infty$, in order to obtain a bounded function we need to scale $f(k) $ by $1/n^2$ to obtain
$$\frac{f(k)}{n^2}=\frac{k^2}{n^2}-\frac{k}{n^2}+1+\frac 1n$$
and defining $u= \frac k n \in [-1,1]$
$$F(u) = \lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{f(k)}{n^2} =u^2+1$$
while for $x\ge n$ we have
$$f(x)=2nx \implies \frac{f(k)}{n^2}=2\frac k n\implies F(u)=2|u|$$

Here is an animation for the approximation process with $n$ from $1$ to $30$ (in green, dotted, is the function $x^2+1$):


you are right, the graph does appear to be a straight line for |x|>n. However i am more interested in what happens for |x|<n.

cool animation!

Yes, thanks! convergence seems really slow.

Well the shape of the graph might appear like the one of a parabola but obviously even after precise approximations it will never be a parabola, because the basic definition of a parabola is the locus of points equidistant from a fixed line and a fixed point which sadly will never be the case with such approximated linear modulo functions.
And also they are not exactly curved, when you zoom out they look like they are curved but they are just a bunch of straight lines.

if you take the limit as i tends to infinity and the increment(call it h) tends to 0 will it still be staright lines or will the curve become differentiable and smooth?

The curve indeed will be become smooth but it still will never be anything close to a parabola @tensorman666

You need to justify what you say.
